# Mouse pointer randomly skips to top corner of screen

Tags: mouse, hp

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop. (Getting tired of Win10 bugs.) However, with everything installed and seeming fine I have a problem with my mouse pointer. It randomly skips from its current position to the top corner of the screen. I had this problem in windows, but disabling the pen drivers (the laptop is a HP Envy with a touch screen and pen) solved the problem. I am wondering if I can try the same in Ubuntu, but I don't know where to start!
Any help would be appreciated.